# Laravel 5 Error - Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::make() must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container::make

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php, declaration, contracts, illuminate-container

After composer update and installing contracts I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::make() must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container::make($abstract, array $parameters = Array) in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 12
```

Can't find solution, does anyone please knows how to fix it?

I was missing `compiled.php` file in `vendor` folder. So when I pull that back all works as before.

Well, now I get this when I want to login or register:

Class App\User contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifierName)

Comment: Try run the following: `php artisan clear-compiled && php artisan optimize`?

Comment: I was missing compiled file, when I added it to vendor folder it all works as it was, just realized, now I get error when login or register

Comment: Does app/User.php have a method callled `getAuthIdentifierName`?

Comment: And when I run clear-compiled or optimize, this error shows: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()

Comment: Sounds like you're missing dependencies, run `composer install`

Comment: I got this error [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath()

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

Comment: You said something about compiled.php in your composer.json; can you remove that from the include: `{ "files": [] }` or where ever it is.

Comment: It is in vendor folder, when I remove it then I get first error of my post Fatal error: Declaration of Illuminate\Container\Container::make() must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container::make($abstract, array $parameters = Array) in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 12

Comment: So remove your `vendor/compiled.php` file and run `composer update`?

Comment: Getting the same error Declaration of Illuminate\...